# extract string until underscore or hyphen

Tags: bash, shell, cut

I have filenames like:

```
12345V001_Test1-Test2-Test3.jpg
```

or

```
12345V001-Test1_Test2_Test3.tif
```

At the beginning there is always a number, which can also contain letters. This is followed by keywords separated by a hyphen or an underscore.

I need the number which is at the beginning of the file name. Here is my problem that it is not always consistently the same pattern. It can be followed by an underscore or a hyphen.

Example:

`12345V001_Test1-Test2-Test3.jpg` (extract before underscore) -> `12345V001`

`12345V001-Test1_Test2-Test3.jpg` (extract before hyphen) -> `12345V001`

Comment: What do you want exactly? Just the number at the beginning of the filename (`12345`) or the substring before the first `_` or `-` character (`12345V001`) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to parse the text with regexp, such as

```bash
echo '12345V001_Test1-Test2-Test3.jpg' | sed -E 's/^([^_-]*).*$/\1/g'
```

If you are listing the number of all files inside current working directory, you can simply pipe the filename from `ls`

```bash
ls | sed -E 's/^([^_-]*).*$/\1/g'
```

Comment: The `sed` command in this answer is unnecessarily complex. `sed 's/[-_].*//'` is enough to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the filename is stored in a variable `v`, you could get this by

```
prefix=${v%%[_-]*}
```